# "Class is not abstract and does not override method in class" error, but I implemented those methods

Tags: java, interface, overriding, abstract-class, implements

I know there are lots of questions related to this compiler error in Java.
I have to code the behavior of a simple media player that plays images, audio files and videos. I wrote seven classes, three of them being interfaces. Here's a schematic:

- AudioI contains volume-related methods: weaker, louder, getVolume and setVolume;
- VideoI contains brightness-related methods: brighter, darker, getBrightness and setBrightness;
- MediaI contains general methods for media: play, getTitle, setTitle, getDuration and setDuration.

The other classes are:

- Audio: it implements AudioI, MediaI and extends Media;
- Image: it implements VideoI, MediaI and extends Media;
- Video: it implements VideoI, MediaI and extends Media;
- Media: it implements AudioI, VideoI and MediaI;
- InterfaceTest: where I test methods and constructors.

Now, the problem I have is that, even though I think I implemented everything correctly, I get the compiler error in the title. Also, every time I compile, the compiler outputs 4 errors only, related to Audio, Image, Video and Media classes. If I remove one signature in a random interface the compiler switches to another method and tells me it's wrongly implemented. Even if I remove all method signatures except for one, the compiler outputs the error regarding that particular method.

Also, I don't know if this is helpful, I use Java 8 and I don't use an IDE, I compile and run the files from the Windows terminal.

Here's the code:

AudioI interface

```
public interface AudioI{
  public void louder();
  public void weaker();
  public int getVolume();
  public void setVolume();
}
```

VideoI interface

```
public interface VideoI{
  public void brighter();
  public void darker();
  public int getBrightness();
  public void setBrightness();
}
```

MediaI interface

```
public interface MediaI{
  public void play();
  public int getDuration();
  public void setDuration();
  public String getTitle();
  public void setTitle();
}
```

Audio class

```
public class Audio extends Media implements AudioI, MediaI{
  private int volume;
  private int duration;
  private String title;

  /**
    CONSTRUCTORS
  **/
  Audio(){
    this.title = "audio.mp3";
    this.duration = 100;
    this.volume = 5;
  };

  Audio(String title, int duration){
    this.title = title;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.volume = 5;
  };

  /**
    AUDIOI METHODS IMPLEMENTATION
  **/
  public void louder(){
    if(this.volume < 10){
        this.volume++;
    }else{
        System.out.print("Maximum volume reached");
    }
  };

  public void weaker(){
    if(this.volume > 0){
        this.volume--;
    }else{
        System.out.print("Minimum volume reached");
    }
  };

  public int getVolume(){
    return this.volume;
  };

  public void setVolume(int volume){
    if(volume > 9){
        System.out.println("******************************");
        System.out.println("* ERROR: maximum volume is 9 *");
        System.out.println("******************************");
    }else if(volume < 0){
        System.out.println("******************************");
        System.out.println("* ERROR: minimum volume is 0 *");
        System.out.println("******************************");
    }else{
        this.volume = volume;
    }
  };

  /**
    MEDIAI METHODS IMPLEMENTATION
  **/
  public void play(){
    int i;

    System.out.println("TITLE: " + this.title);

    System.out.print("VOLUME: >");
    for(i = 0; i < this.volume; i++){
        System.out.print(")");
    }
    System.out.println("");
  };

  public int getDuration(){
    return this.duration;
  };

  public void setDuration(int duration){
    this.duration = duration;
  };

  public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
  };

  public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
  };
}
```

Image class

```
public class Image extends Media implements VideoI, MediaI{
  private String title;
  private int brightness;
  private int duration = 1;

  /**
    CONSTRUCTORS
  **/
  Image(){
    this.title = "img.jpeg";
    this.brightness = 5;
  };

  Image(String title){
    this.title = title;
    this.brightness = 5;
    this.duration = 1;
  };

  /**
    AUDIOI METHODS IMPLEMENTATION
  **/
  public void brighter(){
    if(this.brightness < 10){
        this.brightness++;
    }else{
        System.out.print("Maximum brightness reached.");
    }
  };

  public void darker(){
    if(this.brightness > 0){
        this.brightness--;
    }else{
        System.out.print("Minimum brightness reached.");
    }
  };

  public int getBrightness(){
    return this.brightness;
  };

  public void setBrightness(int brightness){
    if(brightness > 10){
        System.out.println("* ERROR: maximum brightness is 10 *");
    }else if(brightness < 1){
        System.out.println("* ERROR: minimum brightness is 1 *");
    }else{
        this.brightness = brightness;
    }
  };

  /**
    MEDIAI METHODS IMPLEMENTATION
  **/
  public void play(){
    int i;

    System.out.println("TITOLO: " + this.title);

    System.out.print("LUMINOSITA': >");
    for(i = 0; i < this.brightness; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
  };

  public int getDuration(){
    return this.duration;
  };

  public void setDuration(int duration){
    System.out.println("ERROR: cannot set image duration");
  };

  public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
  };

  public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
  };
}
```

Video class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Video extends Media implements VideoI, MediaI{
  private int duration;
  private String title;
  private int brightness;
  private Image buff;
  ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();

  /**
    CONSTRUCTORS
  **/
  Video(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        images.add(new Image("img" + i + ".jpeg"));
    }
    this.brightness = 5;
    this.duration = 100;
    this.title = "slideshow.mkv";
  };

  Video(String title, int nOfImages){
    for(int i = 0; i < nOfImages; i++){
        buff = new Image("img" + i + ".jpeg");
        this.images.add(buff);
    }
    this.brightness = this.images.get(0).getBrightness();
    this.duration = nOfImages;
    this.title = title;
  };

  /**
    VIDEOI METHODS IMPLEMENTATION
  **/
  public void brighter(){
    int i;

    if(this.brightness < 10){
        this.brightness++;

        for(i = 0; i < this.images.size(); i++){
            this.images.get(i).setBrightness(this.brightness);
        }
    }else{
        System.out.print("Maximum brightness reached.");
    }
  };

  public void darker(){
    int i;

    if(this.brightness > 0){
        this.brightness--;

        for(i = 0; i < this.images.size(); i++){
            this.images.get(i).setBrightness(this.brightness);
        }
    }else{
        System.out.print("Minimum brightness reached.");
    }
  };

  public int getBrightness(){
    return this.brightness;
  };

  public void setBrightness(int brightness){
    if(brightness < 0){
        System.out.println("**********************************");
        System.out.println("* ERROR: minimum brightness is 0 *");
        System.out.println("**********************************");
    }else if(brightness > 10){
        System.out.println("***********************************");
        System.out.println("* ERROR: maximum brightness is 10 *");
        System.out.println("***********************************");
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < this.images.size(); i++){
            this.images.get(i).setBrightness(brightness);
            this.brightness = brightness;
        }
    }
  };

  /**
    MEDIAI METHODS IMPLEMENTATION
  **/
  public void play(){
    int i;

    System.out.println("TITOLO: " + this.title);

    System.out.print("LUMINOSITA': >");
    for(i = 0; i < this.brightness; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");


    System.out.print("DURATA VIDEO: ");
    for(i = 0; i < this.images.size(); i = i + 10){
        System.out.print("[] ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
  };

  public int getDuration(){
    this.duration = this.images.size();
    return this.duration;
  };

  public void setDuration(int duration){
    System.out.println("ERROR: cannot set video duration");
  };

  public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
  };

  public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
  };
}
```

Media class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Media implements AudioI, VideoI, MediaI{
  private Video video;
  private Audio audio;
  private String title;
  private int duration;
  private int volume;
  private int brightness;
  private boolean hasVideo;
  private boolean hasAudio;

  /**
    CONSTRUCTORS
  **/

  Media(){
    this.title = "Video.mkv";
    this.volume = 5;
    this.brightness = 5;
    this.hasVideo = false;
    this.hasAudio = false;
  };

  Media(String title, Audio audio, Video video){
    this.video = video;
    this.audio = audio;
    this.title = title + ".mkv";
    this.volume = audio.getVolume();
    this.brightness = video.getBrightness();
    if(this.audio.getDuration() >= this.video.getDuration()){
        this.duration = this.audio.getDuration();
    }else{
        this.duration = this.video.getDuration();
    }
    this.hasVideo = true;
    this.hasAudio = true;
  };

  Media(String title, Audio audio){
    this.audio = audio;
    this.title = title + ".mp3";
    this.volume = audio.getVolume();
    this.duration = this.audio.getDuration();
    this.hasVideo = false;
    this.hasAudio = true;
  };

  Media(String title, Video video){
    this.video = video;
    this.title = title + ".sdw";
    this.brightness = video.getBrightness();
    this.duration = this.video.getDuration();
    this.hasVideo = true;
    this.hasAudio = false;
  };

  /**
    MEDIAI METHODS IMPLEMENTATION
  **/

  public void play(){
    int i;

    System.out.println("TITOLO: " + this.title);

    if(this.hasAudio == true){
        System.out.print("VOLUME: >");
        for(i = 0; i < this.audio.getVolume(); i++){
            System.out.print(")");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    if(this.hasVideo == true){
        System.out.print("LUMINOSITA': >");
        for(i = 0; i < this.video.getBrightness(); i++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    if(this.hasVideo == true && this.hasAudio == true){
        System.out.print("DURATA AUDIO: ");
        for(i = 0; i < this.video.getDuration(); i = i + 10){
            System.out.print("[] ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("DURATA VIDEO: ");
        for(i = 0; i < this.audio.getDuration(); i = i + 10){
            System.out.print("[] ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
  };

  public void setAudio(Audio audio){
    this.audio = audio;
  };


  public void setVideo(Video video){
    this.video = video;
  };

  public int getDuration(){
    return this.duration;
  };

  public void setDuration(int duration){
    System.out.println("ERROR: cannot modify media duration");
  };


  public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
  };

  public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
  };

  /**
    AUDIOI METHODS IMPLEMENTATION
  **/

  public void louder(){
    this.audio.louder();
  };

  public void weaker(){
    this.audio.weaker();
  };

  public int getVolume(){
    return this.audio.getVolume();
  };

  public void setVolume(int volume){
    this.audio.setVolume(volume);
  };

  /**
    VIDEOI METHODS IMPLEMENTATION
  **/

  public void brighter(){
    this.video.brighter();
  };

  public void darker(){
    this.video.darker();
  };

  public int getBrightness(){
    return this.video.getBrightness();
  };

  public void setBrightness(int brightness){
    this.video.setBrightness(brightness);
  };
}
```

Comment: Sadly, no. My professors are a bit old fashioned! But if you think running the code on an IDE could be helpful I'll try right away

Comment: Note: There's no reason to put `;` after the block of a method or constructor. It doesn't actually prevent compilation *(I'm surprised to find)*, but it's not expected or required.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah I also thought so, but since I'm a noob in Java who knows, maybe it was the problem :) Also, I think the compiler doesn't give me an error for that because it reads the ";" as a null instruction

Comment: @alemootasa: Yup, it's an [empty statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6). I'm just surprised empty statements are valid there. :-)

Comment: You would see your error if you attached the `@Override` annotation to each of the implementing methods, which you should always do.

Comment: It's interesting that `Video` extends `Media`, which contains a `Video` pointer. So what is the meaning of the `Video` member of a `Video` instance?

Comment: `if(this.hasVideo == true)` Comparing a `boolean` to a `boolean` to get a `boolean` is somewhat redundant, superfluous, and repetitive.

Comment: @LewBloch 1: I didn't know what an annotation was, I didn't get to that part yet, but thank you for the suggestion, I quickly searched what an annotation was and it's very helpful. 2: In the test class I use the constructors in Media to test the code, and I need a Video instance in two cases, that's why the class Video exists. Did I answer you? Frankly I didn't quite get your question, sorry! 3: I didn't find the line you mentioned, but in any case, what would you suggest instead? As I said, I'm a noob at Java, I didn't pick up the style yet

Comment: `if (hasVideo)`, or as a method, if (hasVideo()) {` (I made it a method and`this.` for a method has no effect.) `Video` extends `Media`. `Media` has a `Video` member, so all its subclasses do, too. Thus, `Video` has within it a `Video` member, and has a `setVideo()` method. My question was what it means in the domain logic for a `Video` to have a `Video` member; in other​ words, what does `Video.setVideo(someVideo)` mean?

Comment: See the Java Tutorial again for an explanation of annotations, and `@Override` in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem seems to be with your `set` methods, within the *interfaces*, you've declared that the `set` methods will **not** have a parameter but within the *classes* that implement those *interfaces* you instead provided parameters for them i.e you're **not** implementing the appropriate methods from the *interfaces* but rather defining a new method completely different to the ones within the *interfaces*.

The solution is simply to change the `set` method definitions of the *interfaces* to match the ones within the *classes* or vice versa.

Comment: Tried that (I thought method signatures didn't require a parameter declaration/specification) but didn't work: if I just add the parameter type between the brackets in methods signatures (like 'void setVolume(int)') the compiler tells me to specify a identifier, if I add a identifier the previous compiler error pops up again

Comment: And I said a stupid thing: don't know what happened, maybe I didn't save my source code and I got the same compiler message (a huge thanks to my professors that don't let us use an IDE). Sorry for my previous comment, you were obviously correct. Thank you!

Comment: @alemootasa Glad it helped and your problem is now solved ^^.

Answer (score -1):

Since the Media class already implements the interfaces AudioI, VideoI and MediaI, to the classes Audio and Video don't implements the interfaces and than see that happens